How can I match whitespace outside of HTML comments with RegEx?
I would like to replace instances of "\n", "\t", and "    " (four spaces) in RegEx, but preserve all whitespace inside of an HTML comment block. Unfortunately, the comment can contain anything, including other HTML tags, so I have to match "<!--" and "-->" specifically. Furthermore, there may be multiple instances of comments with whitespace to match in between. I can use multiple RegEx expressions if needed, but I cannot modify the HTML content aside from the replacement.
Here is some sample code to experiment with:
<div>
    <p>Sample text!</p>
    <!--
        <img src="test.jpg" alt="This is an image!" width="500" height="600">
    -->
</div>
<div>
    <p>Sample text!</p>
    <!--
        <img src="test.jpg" alt="This is an image!" width="500" height="600">
    -->
</div>
<div>
    <p>Sample text!</p>
    <!--
        <img src="test.jpg" alt="This is an image!" width="500" height="600">
    -->
</div>

In this instance, all sets of four spaces should be matched except for the ones in each comment (lines 4, 5, 10, 11, 16, 17).
I have already split up my expressions into one for each type of whitespace, and I have been experimenting with spaces. The closest I have gotten is this:
/(?<!<!--.*?(?<!-->.*?))    (?!(?!.*?<!--).*?-->)/gs

which matches instances of tabs not in the first or last comment block, but it does match tabs in the middle comment blocks which is incorrect. However I suspect it could be accomplished by modifying something in the second half:
/    (?!(?!.*?<!--).*?-->)/gs

Any suggestions? Is this even possible?
UPDATE: In this situation I am not trying to match opening tags; rather, I want the whitespace outside of a specific element (and in this case, the comment block does not have the same syntax as other elements anyways). My ultimate goal here was to use it for a heavily customized instance of TinyMCE in which I wanted to prevent whitespace from being clobbered using the protect attribute. This specifically takes a list of regular expressions and does its own replace with its own <!--mce:protected %0A--> type comment.
After I posted this I then realized that I could just protect the entire comment separately because it would not show up in the editor regardless...

Regular expressions are not good at determining "inside" and "outside".

This question is similar to: RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I'm having a hard time understanding what you're trying to ultimately accomplish here. Are you just trying to convert all comments to be single-line? Please provide your desired output.

Instead of lookarounds, you could match the comments first and then keep them as is. Then alternatively remove all 4 white spaces.
Such as
/(<!--.*?-->)|    /gs

and replace it with $1.
See the test case


const text = `<div>
    <p>Sample text!</p>
    <!--
        <img src="test.jpg" alt="This is an image!" width="500" height="600">
    -->
</div>
<div>
    <p>Sample text!</p>
    <!--
        <img src="test.jpg" alt="This is an image!" width="500" height="600">
    -->
</div>
<div>
    <p>Sample text!</p>
    <!--
        <img src="test.jpg" alt="This is an image!" width="500" height="600">
    -->
</div>`;


const output = text.replace(/(<!--.*?-->)|    /gs, '$1');

console.log(output);




Very clever! The only drawback is you have to include the $1 in your replacement (which would not have worked in my specific use case), but if you want to replace with other text it's as simple as text.replace(/    (<!--.*?-->)|    /gs, '<replacement>$1');

@Jonathan You could also specify a function to test if the group one is successfully captured and replace it conditionally:text.replace(/(<!--.*?-->)|    /gs, (_, $1) => $1 ? $1 : '<replacement>')

The node interface is an approach you can try.  Parse your string to a html fragment and walk through the nodes cleaning them up.
If you need to handle more types of nodes you can add them to the switch and refer to the list here


const str = `<div>
    <p>Sample text!</p>
    <!--
        <img src="test.jpg" alt="This is an image!" width="500" height="600">
    -->
</div>
<div>
    <p>Sample text!</p>
    <!--
        <img src="test.jpg" alt="This is an image!" width="500" height="600">
    -->
</div>
<div>
    <p>Sample text!</p>
    <!--
        <img src="test.jpg" alt="This is an image!" width="500" height="600">
    -->
</div>`;

const transformNodes = (nodes) => {
  nodes.forEach(node => {
    switch (node.nodeType) {
      case Node.COMMENT_NODE:
        // don't change comments
      break;
      case Node.TEXT_NODE:
        // trim text nodes
        node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.trim();
      break;
      case Node.ELEMENT_NODE:
        // recurse elements
        transformNodes(node.childNodes);
      break;
    }
  });
};

const el = document.createElement('body');
el.innerHTML = str;
transformNodes(el.childNodes);
console.log(el.innerHTML);




Looks like a saner version of NodeIterator

I would probably have chosen this solution if I wasn't limited to RegEx. Scalability is nice!
